# Prove $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{D} \cup \{(0,1)\}$ aren't homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

They give me $\mathbb{D}$ = {$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2 + y^2 < 1$} and they ask me to prove that $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{D} \cup \{(0,1)\}$ aren't homeomorphic.

My idea to prove this is using $f \colon \mathbb{D} \cup \{(0,1)\} \to \mathbb{D}$ and taking the fundamental group of $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{f(0,1)\}$ in one random point, so the first one has the trivial set as fundamental group and the second has something different, so as the fundamental group is a homeomorphism invariant they aren't homeomorphic.

I don't know if it is ok or not.

Comment: This issue confused me too, but I think now that $(0,1)$ is not an open interval in $\mathbb R$, it is instead ordered pair notation for a point in $\mathbb R^2$. Perhaps the OP could confirm.

Comment: Yes, (0,1) is a point of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: @Alvaro Good that you added the braces! I’ll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name $P=(0,1)$ and  $\mathbb D^\prime = \mathbb D \cup \{P\}$.

If $\mathbb D$ and $\mathbb D^\prime$ would be homeomorphic, $\mathbb D =\mathbb D^\prime \setminus \{P \}$ would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb D $ minus a point. But that can’t be as $\mathbb D$ minus a point is not simply connected while $\mathbb D$ is.

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ minus a point is not simply connected because it doesn't satisfy that the fundamental group is the trivial one or because it doesn't satisfy the path-connected property?

Comment: Because it doesn’t satisfy the fact that its fundamental group is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb D$ is a $2$-manifold: $\mathbb D \cup\{(0,1)\}$ is not, as no neighbourhood of $(0,1)$ in it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.  For example, no neighbourhood of $(0,1)$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right idea, but you need to be more careful about how you phrase your argument. The key point is that every point $x\in\mathbb{D}$ has the property that $\mathbb{D} \setminus x \simeq S^1$, but $(\mathbb{D}\cup \{(0,1)\}) \setminus (0,1) = \mathbb{D} \simeq *$. If there were a homeomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{D}\cup \{(0,1)\} \to \mathbb{D}$ then we would have to have both $S^1 \simeq \mathbb{D}\setminus f(0,1) \simeq *$, which is a contradiction since $S^1$ is not contractible.

Comment: Why can we affirm that $\mathbb{D}$\ $x$ ~ $\mathbb{S^1}$? And also what do you mean with $*$?

Comment: You could prove it by first giving a homeomorphism $\mathbb{D}\setminus x \cong \mathbb{D}\setminus 0$, and then a deformation retraction of the latter space onto the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$. By $*$ I just mean a one point space, so by $X\simeq *$ I just mean $X$ is contractible.